# Failure to load resource 500 error ajax POST in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have seen many other posts like this, but I cannot see anything I have done wrong.  I also read it could be a problem with the hosting (Heroku) so I have created a ticket, but no answer after 3 days.

Below is the code which sends the info:

(discuss.php)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#ideasubmit').click(function() {
                console.log();
                $('#ideacontainer').append('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Please Wait" id="idealoading" />');

                var ideatitle = $('#ideatitle').val();
                var ideafbid = $('#ideafbid').val();
                var idea = $('#idea').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajaxsqli.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'ideatitle=' + ideatitle + '&ideafbid=' + ideafbid + '&idea=' + idea,

                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#idearesponse').remove();
                        $('#ideacontainer').append('<p id="idearesponse">' + result + '</p>');
                        $('#idealoading').fadeOut(500, function() {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Below here is the code file which gets the error when it sent the info:

(ajaxsqli.php)

```
    $db = new db;

$query = "INSERT into comments(user_fbid, discuss_type, discuss_post_title, discuss_post, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, )";

$stmt = $db->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('iissi', $_POST['ideafbid'], 1, $_POST['ideatitle'], $_POST['idea'], date('Ymd'));
    $stmt->execute();
}

if($stmt) {
echo "Thank you. We'll be in touch with you shortly!";
} else {
echo "There was a problem. Please  try again later.";
}

?>
```

Whats odd is I had it working 3 days ago, and I went to improve some of the code and now I am unable to make it work, even if I restore the back up.

This is the full error message:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) and points to ajaxsqli.php

Using Chrome Inspect Elements I can see the POST is posting the information, but no response information.

Is there anything wrong with this code ?

Comment: as it says: 500 is an internal server error. check your apache error and access log.

Answer (score 1):

A `500` error usually refers to a problem in the php. Load `ajaxsqli.php` in the browser with the paramaters (change `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` and then you can use the querystring. EG

```
$db = new db;

$query = "INSERT into comments(user_fbid, discuss_type, discuss_post_title, discuss_post, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, )";

$stmt = $db->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('iissi', $_REQUEST['ideafbid'], 1, $_REQUEST['ideatitle'], $_REQUEST['idea'], date('Ymd'));
    $stmt->execute();
}

if($stmt) {
echo "Thank you. We'll be in touch with you shortly!";
} else {
echo "There was a problem. Please  try again later.";
}

?>
```

Then go to http://yourhost/ajaxsqli.php?ideafbid=data&ideatitle=data&idea=data and see what the PHP error is

Comment: also `ajaxsqli.php` doesn't have an opening `<?php` tag

Comment: Not having any luck, there is no error message, but this is what the browser states: 

The website encountered an error while retrieving https://online-parliament.herokuapp.com/ajaxsqli.php?ideatitle=poop&ideafbid=878987879878798789&idea=poopoopo. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: Changed part of the PHP file to check, as I have not used sqli before:
$db = new db;
$query = "INSERT into comments(user_fbid, discuss_type, discuss_post_title, discuss_post, date) VALUES ("
 . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ideafbid']) . ", 1,'"
 . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ideatitle']) . "','"
 . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['idea']) . "',"
 . date('Ymd');
$result = $db-query($query);

Comment: I also changed it to $_REQUEST but still not error but again looking at Google Elements I can see the query in the URL is working okay?